# Creating arrow patterns

Tags: building, snot

What methods are there to creating  convincing looking arrow patterns on walls and floors? (Without stickers or printed pieces)

My current solution is to use "relief" building with slope pieces, which looks pretty good but aren't flat:

[image]

This is using the headlight piece, which allows many interesting possibilities:

[image]

I'm also aware of various solutions using the tiny slopes, such as this sideways construction for chevrons used on the Horizion Express:

[image]

There's also sloped striping using 1 plate offset that have a tiny gap and I'm not sure if they can create proper arrow patterns (the head of the arrow should be triangular and not wedge shaped).

[image]

Looking through slope pieces, I found 3044c which allows this small 2x2 arrow:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest against using headlight bricks as shown on your example if you are looking forward building something on top of them.

Answer (score 3):

Another convenient way I found is with the new triangular 2x2 tiles. The only issue is that the color selection is a little limited. For simple pentagon shape, Modified 2 x 3 Pentagonal Tile is quite versatile.

[image]